# How to express the probability $P(X \text{ mod } 2 = 0)$ that an integer-valued $X$ is even using characteristic function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose $X$ is an integer-valued random variable. My question is, how can I express the probability $P(X \text{ mod } 2 = 0)$ that $X$ is even knowing the characteristic function $\phi_X(t)$? Can I do it without using a general inversion formula by summing up $P(X=2k)$ over $k \in \mathbb{Z}$? Maybe, I could use some sort of simpler argument and end up with some nice expression?

I almost don't have any idea. I tried to use $\phi_X(2t) = \sum\limits_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} e^{2ikt}P(X=k)$, but it just doesn't work. Do I miss something trivial here?

Actually, this is only a part of the problem that I'm trying to solve. Another part is the following:

> Let $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ is a sequence of i.i.d random variables, and $P(X_1 \text{ mod } 2 = 0) = p \in (0, 1)$. Let $Y_n = X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_n$. Prove that $P(Y_n \text{ mod } 2 = 0) = 1/2$.

And I want to solve this problem using characteristic functions. I suspect, for this I would need to find $\phi_{Y_n}(t) = (\phi_{Z_1}(t))^n$ with $Z_i = X_i \text{ mod } 2$.

Comment: Well you would use the inverse Fourier transform to find the distribution. But I mean...the parity of $X$ is just a Bernoulli random variable.

Comment: @TrevorGunn Yes, I understand that, but can I find this distribution without using inverse Fourier transformation directly?

Comment: But the distribution of $X$ could be so many things (and hence so could $Y$). Like fix two infinite series $x_n , y_n$ where $\sum x_n = p$ and $\sum y_n = 1 - p$ and suppose that $P(X = 2n) = x_n$ and $P(X = 2n + 1) = y_n$. There's infinite flexibility.

Comment: @TrevorGunn my problem consists of two parts: a) express $P$($X$ is even) with a characteristic function of $X$; b) using this, solve the problem. I think, I know how to solve b) using a), but I don’t know how to solve a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok let's try something else. We'll start with the probability generating function

$$f_X(q) = \sum_{k \in \mathbf Z} \mathrm{P}(X = k) q^k. $$

So the characteristic function is where $q = e^{it}$.

Notice:

1. $f_{Y_n} = f_X^n$
2. $\displaystyle \tfrac12(f_X(q) + f_X(-q)) = \sum_{k \text{ even}} \mathrm{P}(X = k) q^k$

This is called ["bisecting" the series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection).

So the probability that $Y$ is even is

$$\mathrm{P}(Y \text{ is even}) = \frac{f_X(1)^n + f_X(-1)^n}{2} = \frac12 + \frac{f_X(-1)^n}{2}.$$

You can write this in terms of the characteristic function by choosing appropriate values for $q = e^{it}$ (namely $t = 0, t = \pi$).

Also notice that

$$\mathrm{P}(X \text{ is even}) = p = \frac12 + \frac{f_X(-1)}{2}. $$

So combining these gives the limit of $1/2$.

Comment: By the way: if the $X_i$'s are not identically distributed, the same proof still works but now we have to use $f_{Y_n}(q) = f_{X_1}(q) \cdots f_{X_n}(q)$. The special values at $q = 1, q = -1$ are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're making this way too complicated. $Y_n$ is even if and only if an even number of $\{X_1, \dots, X_n\}$ are odd. So

$$P(Y_n \text{ is even}) = \sum_{k \text{ even}} \binom{n}{k} (1 - p)^kp^{n-k}.$$

So one strategy is to compare this sum to the expansion of $(p + q)^n$ where $q = 1 - p$ (so of course $p + q = 0$).

For instance, one can show that

$$\sum_{k \text{ even}} \binom{n}{k} = \sum_{k \text{ odd}} \binom{n}{k},$$

by looking at the binomial expansion of $(1 - 1)^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sure, this is an easy problem. But for educational purposes, it was meant (by the author of the book) to be solved using characteristic functions in two steps:  a) express $P$($X$ is even) with a characteristic function of $X$; b) using this, solve the problem. I think, I know how to solve b) using a), but I don’t know how to solve a).